# ASP.NET webforms - Request.Form["SAMLResponse"] Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, webforms, saml

I have been trying to login in my web forms application using azure SSO via saml but I cannot get the SAMLResponse from Request.Form["SAMLResponse"],it always returns null. I've been using the nuget Aspsamlnet on [github](https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml) in my asp.net webforms project.

below is the code im using in my login button from my login page to redirect to the callback/redirect URL which is where I will handle and get the SAMLResponse

```
var samlEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/id_here/saml2/";

var request = new AuthRequest(
               "https://localhost:44342", // TODO: Put your app's "entity ID" here
               "https://localhost:44342/frmSSOLogin.aspx" // TODO: Put Assertion Consumer URL (where the provider should redirect users after authenticating)
           );

           var redirectUrl = request.GetRedirectUrl(samlEndpoint);
           Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

And below is the web forms page where I tried to get the SAMLResponse but i'm always receiving this error:

> Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: s

```
            string certificate = @"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
certificate here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

            var samlResponse = new Response(certificate, Request.Form["SAMLResponse"]);
```

I've tried to use this codes:

```
var samlResponsees = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["SAMLResponse"];
var samlResponsee = Request.Form;
var samlResponseee = Request.Form["SAMLResponse"];
var samlRespoense2 = Page.Request.Form["SAMLResponse"];
```

and also made sure that the callback URL is the same in the azure configuration and in my code. SSO saml configuration was setup to accept POST request.

I also followed this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/active-directory-sso-in-windows-azure-using-saml-2-0/) to setup SAML SSO in Azure on get the SAMLResponse but still returns null

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: Did you tried "Request.Form["SAMLResponse"].ToString()"

Comment: yes. I also tried that but still did not work

Comment: Then you have to do null checker by condition. Otherwise there is no solution for that.

Comment: yes i i have a null checker. but would you know why it's always returning null? i have followed the instructions carefully.

Comment: I think it might be a data binding issue.

Comment: Hi Sheno,
can you please elaborate? do we have a fix for this?